# How do you change the key that the :id field is passed on in a resourceful route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In a rails resourceful route e.g.

```
resource :users
```

The user_id will be passed to the controller via the :id parameter

```
@user_id = params[:id`]
```

However when you nest another resource within the original:

```
resource :users do
  resource :questions
end
```

the user id is then passed via the :user_id paramter

```
@user_id = params[:user_id]
@question_id = params[:id]
```

Is there any way to enforce the naming of the :id key such that it is consistent?

Answer (score 0):

One way to make the names consistent would be to rename the attribute in @user to be user_id instead of id and using this as the primary key. You could do this by rolling back your database and modifying the migration for your user class and changing the attributes there.

Another way you could make them consistent is to have a method within your user class that returns the current_user. Then you can always call the user through this syntax.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. I have effectively gone with the latter method but was still keen to know whether there was actually an effective way of specifying the keys themselves

Comment: Well, if you're going with the latter method, you can always just call current_user.id. This returns the id of the User object that is logged in.